# How to remove the elevation in DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter, drop-down-menu, widget

help me to remove this elevation in DropdownButton, I tried using `elevation = 0`, but nothing happened or if you have better widget to display item like DropdownButton please show me.

[image]

thank you

Comment: Are you meaning the underline as elevation? Can you also add your dropdown widget code?

Comment: oww sorry its my bad I though it was a elevation hahaha, so it was just an underline thank you for reminding me haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the underline we should wrap the `DropdownButton` widget with the `DropdownButtonHideUnderline` widget.

The `elevation` property will make the drop-down layer elevated when it's in the open state.

**Example**

```
DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
          child: DropdownButton(
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            items: <String>[
              'Android',
              'IOS',
              'Flutter',
              'Python',
            ].map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            hint: Text(
              "Please choose a langauage",
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.black,
                  fontSize: 16,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
            ),
            onChanged: (value) {
              print(value);
            },
          ),
        ),
```